# Why does the express server does not serve the compressed .gz files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, compression

I have got this express config :

```
.....

const app = module.exports = express();

app.get('*.js', function(req, res, next) {
  req.url = req.url + '.gz';
  res.set('Content-Encoding', 'gzip');
  res.set('Content-Type', 'text/javascript');
  next();
});

app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

....
```

My webpack config seems correct since all the js chunks in public/views are created and compressed with gzip.

```
|public
    |views
        |...
        |hash.chunk.js
        |hash.chunk.js.gz
        |....
```

However, the server keeps serving the js chunks which are not compressed with gzip.

Would you have any idea why ?

**EDIT**

When i delete my original js chunks (not compressed), I can still load the website. That should mean that the compressed gzip files are served, no ? However, when I check in the chrome dev tools the response header of any chunk, there is no header : Content-encoding : gzip

Comment: `res.set('Content-Type', 'text/javascript');` — The correct content-type for JavaScript is `application/javascript`.

Comment: When I check google dev tools, I have this type of response header though : 

HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
X-Powered-By: Express
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Cache-Control: public, max-age=0
Last-Modified: Mon, 28 May 2018 17:06:04 GMT
ETag: W/"f2a4-163a7b6c97d"
Date: Mon, 28 May 2018 17:11:47 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

Which does not seem to serve the gzip file ?

Comment: I don't have any header : Content-Encoding: gzip

Comment: Of course you don't. The status is `304 Not Modified` so there is no content in the response to describe the encoding of. The browser will use the cached version it already has.

Comment: Oh of course ! It works then :) Thank you !